# Flutter web null idToken GoogleSignIn

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use google api to login(without firebase) for a flutter web app

I have a default web application OAuth credential created in my google console and I am using the clientID in this code.

Am I missing something? Please help.

```
late GoogleSignInAccount account;
late GoogleSignInAuthentication auth;
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(clientId: '*****.apps.googleusercontent.com',scopes: ['email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"],);
GoogleSignInAccount? user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
account = googleSignIn.currentUser!;
auth = await account.authentication;
print(auth.idToken);
```

Comment: I also have added <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com"> in my web/index.html

also have consent screen configured in my credentials console.

However idToken received is null, and accesstoken is working